# Best way to handle stream of UDP data in android application

Tags: android, multithreading, udp, video-streaming

This is an architectural question about the best way to receive UDP data on android.

I am sending a video stream from a custom hardware device over a wifi link.  I have some hardware limitations on my device so the video stream is made up of a series of JPEG images.  Each image is broken up into a bunch of packets and sent in pieces over UDP (TCP is also an option here).

I have an android tablet device that is connecting to my custom imaging hardware and receiving its data.  Currently I have a thread that sits in a loop waiting for UDP packets. When a packet is received I create a data bundle and send it back as part of a message to the main thread. In the handler on the main thread I take the byte array from the message and pass it to a method that tries to reconstruct the jpeg image.  If successful it creates an Bitmap using the BitmapFactory and shoves it into a queue (this step is probably stupid). The main thread then dequeues the image and puts in the ImageView.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do things. Is there a way to avoid moving data back to the main thread and if so how do I get the reconstructed image to the UI thread.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Move everything except the bitmap rendering off your main thread.

Comment: I'm not sure how best to do that. Do I create the bitmap and store it in memory in a separate thread and then send back the image to main thread through a message?  Are there any efficiency issues passing large amounts of data like a Bitmap from one thread to the other?